# Formal proof for supremum of $A=\{1+\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is $2$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

Let $A=\{1+\frac{1}{n}:n\in\mathbb{N}\}$. By intuition, I know the supremum is $2$. I want to prove that $2$ is $\sup(A)$ formally using this definition:

> Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be bounded above set. Then $u$ is called least upper bound (supremum) of $A$ if:
> (i) $u$ is upper bound of $A$, i.e. $a\leq u$, for all $a\in A$.
> (ii) $u$ is least upper bound of $A$, i.e. for all $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $c\in A$ such that $u-\varepsilon<c.$

For (i), we know that $\frac{1}{n}\leq 1$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. So, we can get $1+\frac{1}{n}\leq 2$, for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. From this, we have proved that $2$ is upper bound of $A$.

For (ii). Let $\varepsilon>0$. I want to show that there exists $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $2-\varepsilon<1+\frac{1}{n}$. This is my attempt:
\begin{align*}
2-\varepsilon<1+\frac{1}{n}\\
1-\varepsilon<\frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}

I want to manipulate $1-\varepsilon<\frac{1}{n}$ such that I can use Archimedian Property, but I  got stuck there.

Can anyone show that $2$ is least upper bound of $A$?

Comment: Have you tried $n = 1$?

Comment: You have shown that 2 is an upper bound of A, and setting $n = 1$ we see that $2$ is in A.  If it is in A and the upper bound of A, it must be the least upper bound of A.

Comment: For all $\epsilon>0$: $2-\epsilon<1+\dfrac11$ !

Comment: @Aniruddha Deshmukh yes, I have.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, $\forall n\in \Bbb N: n\geq 1\Rightarrow \frac 1n\leq 1\Rightarrow 1+\frac 1n \leq 2$, so $2$ is an upper bound of $A$. But $2\in A$, so $maxA=2$, which means that $supA=2$.

Answer (score 0):

You do not even need the Archimedean property. One can show that if a set $A$ has a maximum $m$, then $\sup A = m$. You can easily prove this by seeing that $m$ is an upper bound and if $u$ is an upperbound for $A$ then obviously $m\le u$ because $m \in A$.

Answer (score 0):

Your definition (ii) isn't correct - you have changed the $u$ to $a$, and also letting $a=c$ makes the definition automatically true.

A better definition is that $u$ is a least upper bound if, $\forall c$ with $c$ as an upper bound, $u\le c$.

Your sequence is readily solved by noting that it is monotonic and tightly bounded above by $2$.